# How to allow user to create a redirect from one URL to another URL

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware, laravel-middleware

I am trying to allow a user (these would only be admin) to redirect one URL to another URL (I own all of these URLs so I am able to redirect them). I am currently passing the URLs they enter from the view to the controller but I am unable to figure out how I can pass this data from my controller to my middleware.

In my controller I tried to use the HttpContext.Items dictionary to set the values for the incoming url and the outgoing url which looks like so.

```cs
public IActionResult RedirectFromView(string userIncomingUrl, string userOutgoingUrl)
{
    HttpContext.Items["incomingUrl"] = userIncomingUrl;
    HttpContext.Items["outgoingUrl"] = userOutgoingUrl;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Now I know when it comes to creating middleware that the pipeline is important, in my `program.cs` file I have made the following:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectFromView>("/userIncomingUrl", "/userOutgoingUrl");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Finally, in my middleware I am trying to perform the redirect like this:

```cs
public class RedirectFromView
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string _incomingUrl;
    private readonly string _outgoingUrl;

    public RedirectFromView(RequestDelegate next, string incomingUrl, string outgoingUrl)
    {
        _next = next;
        _incomingUrl = incomingUrl;
        _outgoingUrl = outgoingUrl;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Validate url trying to be hit by user
        var UrlBeingHit = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
        if (UrlBeingHit.Contains == _incomingUrl)
        {
              context.Response.Redirect(_outgoingUrl)
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

I must be taking the complete wrong approach when passing data from my controller to middleware. Please note that I am successfully getting the data from my view to the controller. The problem lies when passing the data from the controller to my middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of this question. I think the scenario you want to achieve is there is a view in your project in your project. After user input the `incomingUrl` and `outgoingUrl` and submit the form, Later request to `incomingUrl` will be redirected to `outgoingUrl` automatically via middleware.

If I don't misunderstand your question, Here is a working demo, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Set(string userIncomingUrl, string userOutgoingUrl)
        {
            //Here i use session to save the url, you can also save it into database

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("incomingUrl", userIncomingUrl);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("outgoingUrl", userOutgoingUrl);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**MiddleWare**

```
public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var incomingUrl = context.Session.GetString("incomingUrl");
            var outgoingUrl = context.Session.GetString("outgoingUrl");

            var originalUrl = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();

            if (incomingUrl!=null)
            {
                // Retrieve the data from HttpContext.Items
                if (originalUrl.Contains(incomingUrl))
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(outgoingUrl);
                }
            }

            // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]

From above demo, You can find when I first access privacy page, it can access successfully, But after I set `Privacy` as `incomingUrl` and `/Home/new` as `outgoingUrl`  in Set page, When I access `Privacy` page again, It will redirect to `new` page automatically.